# Visibility separation in Swift

Tags: swift

Since swift doesn't use headers to specify it's interface, but access modifiers instead, I wondered if there is a good way to split public and private methods (perhaps in files, extensions or just visually). I'm thinking of the Java-esque way of declaring a `FooInterface` and `FooImpl`, but I don't really like the idea. Is there a nicer way to achieve this?

The bottom line is I want to be able to have all public members in one location and the private stuff in another - it just helps to avoid visibility mistakes.

Comment: belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think that you are overthinking it. Don't split classes by visibility. Split them by functionality. You can use categories to split classes into logical sections. Once your classes are small enough, you won't have visibility problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally use the technique of declaring a private extension:

```
private extension MyClass {
}
```

I do that later in the file. However, that only works for methods. Properties still need to be declared in the main type definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare the methods as private:

```
private func doSomething() {

}
```

Comment: As I said... I want to separate that from the public stuff.